# TikZ - foreach, expansion problem, optional argument and node

Tags: tikz-pgf, expansion, foreach, forest, optional-arguments

I am trying to use `foreach` to simplify the 1st env. code in my MN(ot)WE below.

There is an expansion problem regarding the optional argument in the 2nd code. Here is the output.

[image]

How can I fix this ?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\RequirePackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\useforestlibrary{linguistics}

\newcommand\ptreeComment[3][black]{
    \node [anchor=mid west] at (#2.mid -| ptreecomment coord) {%
        \textcolor{#1}{#3}%
    };
}

\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
    for tree = {%
        sn edges,
        grow'  = 0,
        l      = 2.5cm,
        s sep  = 1.2cm,
        anchor = parent,
    },
    tikz+={
        \coordinate (ptreecomment coord) at (current bounding box.east);
    },
    [
        [$A$
            [$B$, name = nB]
            [$C$, name = nC]
        ]
        [$D$
            [$E$, name = nE]
            [$F$, name = nF]
        ]
    ]
    %
     \ptreeComment{nB}{$X = 1$}
     \ptreeComment[red]{nC}{$X = 3$}
     \ptreeComment[orange]{nE}{$X = 3$}
     \ptreeComment[black!60!green]{nF}{$X = 5$}
\end{forest}

\begin{forest}
    for tree = {%
        sn edges,
        grow'  = 0,
        l      = 2.5cm,
        s sep  = 1.2cm,
        anchor = parent,
    },
    tikz+={
        \coordinate (ptreecomment coord) at (current bounding box.east);
    },
    [
        [$A$
            [$B$, name = nB]
            [$C$, name = nC]
        ]
        [$D$
            [$E$, name = nE]
            [$F$, name = nF]
        ]
    ]
    % 
    \foreach \color/\name/\text in {black/nB/$X = 1$,
                                    red/nC/$X = 3$,
                                    orange/nE/$X = 3$,
                                    black!60!green/nF/$X = 5$}
    {
        \ptreeComment[\color]{\name}{\text}
    }
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

On the other hand, the following code works without problem.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\RequirePackage{tikz}

\newcommand\test[2][black]{
    Option: #1 et Arg: #2\par
}

\newcommand\colorize[2][black]{
    \textcolor{#1}{#2}\par
}

\begin{document}

\foreach \opt/\arg in {black/nB,red/nC,orange/nE,green/nF}{
    \test[\opt]{\arg}
}

\bigskip

\foreach \opt/\arg in {black/nB,red/nC,orange/nE,green/nF}{
    \colorize[\opt]{\arg}
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: If I copy the code and try to compile it, I get `! File ended while scanning use of \forest.` Anyway, using `\color` is obviously a bad choice, since `\textcolor` is defined in terms of `\color`.

Comment: @egreg I have updated the MN(ot)WE.

Answer (score 5):

You should be more careful when choosing names for local variables in `\foreach`:

```
% xcolor.sty, line 756:
\def\textcolor#1#{\@textcolor{#1}}

% xcolor.sty, line 757:
\def\@textcolor#1#2#3{\protect\leavevmode{\color#1{#2}#3}}
```

You're using `\textcolor`, which internally uses `\color`: if you redefine `\color` you can't expect that `\textcolor works; actually you clearly see why the color name is printed.

There is a different way to cope with the problem, without using local variables.

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\useforestlibrary{linguistics}

\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\lforeach}{ s O{} m +m }
 {
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
   {
    \manual_lforeach:non { #2 } { #3 } { #4 }
   }
   {
    \manual_lforeach:nnn { #2 } { #3 } { #4 }
   }
 }

\int_new:N \g__manual_foreach_map_int

\cs_new_protected:Nn \manual_lforeach:nnn
 {
  \keys_set:nn { manual/lforeach } { single }
  \keys_set:nn { manual/lforeach } { #1 }
  \clist_set:Nn \l__manual_lforeach_list_clist { #2 }
  \int_gincr:N \g__manual_foreach_map_int
  \__manual_lforeach_define:n { #3 }
  \clist_map_inline:Nn \l__manual_lforeach_list_clist
   {
    \use:c { __manual_lforeach_ \int_use:N \g__manual_foreach_map_int _action:w } ##1 \q_stop
   }
  \int_gdecr:N \g__manual_foreach_map_int
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \manual_lforeach:nnn { no }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__manual_lforeach_define:n
 {
  \exp_last_unbraced:NcV
   \cs_set:Npn
   { __manual_lforeach_ \int_use:N \g__manual_foreach_map_int _action:w }
   \l__manual_lforeach_format_tl
   \q_stop
   {#1}
 }

\keys_define:nn { manual/lforeach }
 {
  format .tl_set:N = \l__manual_lforeach_format_tl,
  single .code:n = \tl_set:Nn \l__manual_lforeach_format_tl { ##1 },
  double .code:n = \tl_set:Nn \l__manual_lforeach_format_tl { ##1/##2 },
  triple .code:n = \tl_set:Nn \l__manual_lforeach_format_tl { ##1/##2/##3 },
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand\ptreeComment[3][black]{%
    \node [anchor=mid west] at (#2.mid -| ptreecomment coord) {%
        \textcolor{#1}{#3}%
    };
}

\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
    for tree = {%
        sn edges,
        grow'  = 0,
        l      = 2.5cm,
        s sep  = 1.2cm,
        anchor = parent,
    },
    tikz+={
        \coordinate (ptreecomment coord) at (current bounding box.east);
    },
    [
        [$A$
            [$B$, name = nB]
            [$C$, name = nC]
        ]
        [$D$
            [$E$, name = nE]
            [$F$, name = nF]
        ]
    ]
    % 
    \lforeach[triple]% triple means #1/#2/#3
     {
      black/nB/$X = 1$,
      red/nC/$X = 3$,
      orange/nE/$X = 3$,
      black!60!green/nF/$X = 5$
     }
     {\ptreeComment[#1]{#2}{#3}}
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

The macro `\lforeach` has an optional argument for stating options; the possible ones are

- `single` (default), when you only want to cycle over a standard comma separated list;
- `double` if the list is of the form `1/a,2/b,...` and the items before and after the `/` are referred to with `#1` and `#2`;
- `triple` if the list is of the form `1/a/i,2/b/ii,... (used in the example);
- `format` to choose whatever delimiters you wish, with any number of arguments (up to nine, of course); for instance, `triple` is the same as `format=#1/#2/#3`.

The *-variant expands once the first mandatory argument (if the list is stored in a macro). The first mandatory argument has the list, the second one has the code to be executed, where instead of “variables” you use `#1`, `#2` and so on.

For instance, you get the same output with

```latex
    \lforeach[format=C(#1)N(#2)T(#3)]
     {
      C(black)N(nB)T($X = 1$),
      C(red)N(nC)T($X = 3$),
      C(orange)N(nE)T($X = 3$),
      C(black!60!green)N(nF)T($X = 5$)
     }
     {\ptreeComment[#1]{#2}{#3}}
```

(this is just for showing the possibilities).

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why you define a function to change nodes when all you have to do is create a style.

Here, I created the `my note` style which has 3 arguments : color, name, and text.

```
my note/.style n args={3}{text=#1,name=#2,label={[#1]right:#3}},
my note/.default={black}{}{},
```

[image: screenshot]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\RequirePackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\useforestlibrary{linguistics}

%\newcommand\ptreeComment[3][black]{
%    \node [anchor=mid west] at (#2.mid -| ptreecomment coord) {%
%        \textcolor{#1}{#3}%
%    };
%}

\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
my note/.style n args={3}{text=#1,name=#2,label={[#1]right:#3}},
my note/.default={black}{}{},
    for tree = {%
        sn edges,
        grow'  = 0,
        l      = 2.5cm,
        s sep  = 1.2cm,
        anchor = parent,
    },
    tikz+={
        \coordinate (ptreecomment coord) at (current bounding box.east);
    },
    [
        [$A$
            [$B$,my note]
            [$C$,my note ={red}{nC}{$X=3$}]
        ]
        [$D$
            [$E$,my note ={blue}{nE}{$X=3$}]
            [$F$,my note ={black!60!green}{nF}{$X=5$}]
        ]
    ]
    %
%     \ptreeComment{nB}{$X = 1$}
%     \ptreeComment[red]{nC}{$X = 3$}
%     \ptreeComment[orange]{nE}{$X = 3$}
%     \ptreeComment[black!60!green]{nF}{$X = 5$}
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I know that I can do that. This is a choice of API to work with macros after the tree. I really think that we should always define abstract objects at a place and decorate them at another. This is the same point of view as the one for HTML/CSS. One last thing : I can add several comments for the same node to indicate values of different random variables.

Comment: HTML and CSS are interpreted languages, LaTeX is a compiled language. Why do you want to handle a compiled language as an interpreted language?

Comment: My point of view is from the user's one. In practice my choice works and I don't think that real use cases will break the macro.

Answer (score 1):

The problem comes indeed from the use of the name `\color`. The use of `\col` makes all things work... :-)